# React/Redux: Why can data not be rendered when working with isFetching flag?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to implement an `isFetching` flag that indicates when my data is ready for rendering. But even if the flag works, i.e. jumps from `isFetching = true` to `isFetching = false` after the data has been successfully requested, there is still an error when I try to access data: `cannot read property 'username' of null`

Profile Component

```
class Profile extends React.Component {


  render() {
    const (isFetching, profile) = this.props.profile
    console.log (isFetching)
    console.log (profile)
    return <h1>Hello, {isFetching = "false"? profile[0].username : null}</h1>;
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    const profile= state.profile

  return { profile }
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { logout }
)(Profile);
```

Action

```
export const getProfile = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  // Profile Loading
  dispatch({ type: GET_PROFILE_REQUEST });

  axios
    .get(apiBase + "/profile/", tokenConfig(getState))
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_PROFILE_SUCCESS,
        payload: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
      dispatch({
        type: GET_PROFILE_FAILURE,
      });
    });
};
```

Reducer

```
const initialState = {
  isFetching: false,
  profile: null
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
case GET_PROFILE_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true
      };
case GET_PROFILE_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        profile: action.payload,
        isFetching: false
      };

case GET_PROFILE_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        profile: action.payload,
        isFetching: false
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Redux log for GET_PROFILE_SUCCESS

```
profile
isFetching: false
profile[
  {
    "username": "Daniel",
    "id": 1,
    "profile": {
      "image": "Test",
      "bio": "Test"
    }
  }
]
```

I'm happy for every clarification.

Comment: profile is an array? so should it be profile[0].username?

Comment: @Apostolos exactly is an array. I updated it to profile[0].username. But the error remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a small error in your code.

```
return <h1>Hello, {isFetching = "false"? profile.username : null}</h1>;
```

You are not checking for the value of `isFetching` but rather setting it again. Also, since profile is an array, you need to get the first element.Replace it with

```
return <h1>Hello, {!isFetching? profile[0].username : null}</h1>;
```

and it should work.